# Dynamically load list of words from API as map in highlight_text: ^1.6.0

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I need to highlight some words in a text. I used [highlight_text 1.6.0](https://pub.dev/packages/highlight_text).

```
Map<String, HighlightedWord> words = {
    "Flutter": HighlightedWord(
        textStyle: textStyle,
    ),
    "words": HighlightedWord(
       
        textStyle: textStyle,
    ),
   
};



TextHighlight(
          text: text,
          words: words,
          matchCase: false,
          textStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 14.0,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
        )
```

It is working fine when given static values.
Is it possible to load the highlighted words from API like a list instead of the map?

```
List=["Flutter", "Words"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume you get this `sample` list from api:

```
List sample = ["Flutter", "Words"];
```

then you can use `fromIterable`:

```
var result = Map<String, HighlightedWord>.fromIterable(sample,
    key: (v) => v,
    value: (v) => HighlightedWord(
          textStyle: textStyle,
        ),
);
```

then use `result` in `TextHighlight`:

```
TextHighlight(
      text: text,
      words: result,
      matchCase: false,
      textStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 14.0,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
  )
```